# Rails 4 gmaps4rails trigger bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 with the gmaps4rails gem. So far so good with implementation.

My question is, how can I set up the marker to trigger a bootstrap modal on click - instead of having the default infowindow popup?

Here is my current controller action

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @spots = Spot.near(params[:search], 50)
  else
    @spots = Spot.all
  end
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@spots) do |spot, marker|
    marker.lat spot.latitude
    marker.lng spot.longitude
    marker.infowindow spot.description
    marker.json ({ title: spot.title })
  end
end
```

Don't even know where to begin with this one. thx!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the code is for the marker, but normally the method to trigger a bootstrap modal is to wrap the view you want to show (I presume this is a map or something) inside the code you would normally use to show a bootstrap modal. Create a file in the view folder and call it `_modal.html.erb` - paste in the standard bootstrap modal code, and within modal_body you can paste the view code you're trying to show.

The button/link you have that is triggering the modal - you seem to be calling it a marker here - should be set with a `:remote => true` option on it (e.g. `<%=link_to(show, show_map_path(map), :remote => true %>`. This tells Rails that you're going to load the map path using AJAX (I don't know what your path is, because you've not posted it, so just use whatever path you need).

You then need to tell the controller what to do when it receives this call. I'd suggest telling it to `render :modal_form` and building a modal_form.js.erb file (in the views section) that will execute your modal.

This file will need the following:

```
$('#modal_container').html("<%= j render :partial => 'modal' %>");

$('#your_modal').modal('show');
```

You need to put a `<div id="modal_container></div>`  somewhere on the page you're trying to load your modal into. The first line of the above file will render your _modal.html.erb file inside the modal_container div, and the second line will cause it to show (change the #your_modal code for whatever id you've given your modal).